# Getting error while comparing two images using opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am facing an issue while comparing two images using OpenCV in Python 2.7

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread("./spot/image1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("./spot/image2.jpg")

diff = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)

result = not np.any(diff) 

if result is True:
    print "The images are the same"
else:
    cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", difference)
    print "the images are different"
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PrgLang\Python\compareImage.py", line 7, in <module>
    diff = cv2.subtract(img1,img2)
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("./spot/image1.jpg"), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)
img2 = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("./spot/image2.jpg"), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)

diff = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)

result = not np.any(diff) 

if result is True:
    print "The images are the same" 
else:
    cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", diff)
    print "the images are different"
```

Comment: You have to resize both the images to same dimensions as (224, 224).

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV subtract function requires the both input arrays (if they are two array, not an array and a scalar) to have the same size and number of channels.

Check if both are RGB or GRAY, and resize one of them to the other size. An only resize is required.